# Duality between hermitian and skew-hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, group-actions

Let $H_n= \lbrace A \in M_n(\mathbb{C}), A^* = A \rbrace$ be the space of hermitian matrices, and let $iH_n= \lbrace A \in M_n(\mathbb{C}), A^* = -A \rbrace$ be the space of skew-hermitian matrices.

I've come cross the statement which says that the following expression

$$<A,B>= Im(Tr(AB)), A \in H_n, B \in iH_n, $$

defines a duality between $H_n$ and $iH_n$.
(Where $Im(Tr(AB))$ is the imaginary part of the trace of the matrix $AB$).

What does the concept of duality mean in this context?

Edit: This fact was actually used to prove the following:

If $G= U(n)$ and it's Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is indentified with $iH_n$. Then using the duality above helps to prove that the co-adjoint action of $G$ on $\mathfrak{g}^*$(Which is identified with $H_n$ using that duality ) is given by conjugation: $Ad^*_{g} \xi= g \xi g^{-1}$.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_system), but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: @azif00 this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! However, I still don't know how to use this to show that $Ad^*_g \xi = g \xi g^{-1}$ ?

Comment: How is the adjoint action defined in your setting?

Comment: Hi @Joppy! If $g \in G$ The  adjoint action $Ad^*_g : \mathfrak{g}^* \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}^*$ is defined by $<Ad^*_gX, \xi>= <X, Ad_g(\xi)>= <X,g \xi g^{-1}>, X \in \mathfrak{g}^* , \xi \in \mathfrak{g}.$ where $<,>$ in this case denotes the pair of duality between $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{g}^*$.

Comment: Right, so $\operatorname{Ad}_g X = g X g^{-1}$. The pairing you have there is $G$-equivariant in the sense that $\langle Ag, g^{-1} B \rangle = \langle A, B \rangle = \langle gA, Bg^{-1} \rangle$ (This is by the cyclic property of the trace). Using these invariances you can move the $g$'s over to the left hand side: $\langle X, g \xi g^{-1} \rangle = \langle X g^{-1}, \xi g^{-1} \rangle = \langle g X g^{-1}, \xi \rangle$ and you should have your proof.

Comment: I understand your answer however I have a small doubt; you have proved the G-invariance property for the pairing between $H_n$ and $iH_n$ but you use this property in the last step for the paring between $\mathbb{g}^*$ and $\mathbb{g}$ which are identified with $H_n$, could you elaborate further in this please ?